# Proving that $f$ is invertible

Tags: elementary-set-theory, inverse-function

$\DeclareMathOperator{\dom}{dom}\DeclareMathOperator{\ran}{ran}$I need help in the following exercise, I appreciate all the forms for the demonstration:

> Let $f:A→B$ and $g:B→A$ be functions. Suppose that $y=f(x)$ and only if $x=g(y)$. Prove that $f$ is invertible and $g=f^{−1}$.

By now this is what I have done but I don't reach the goal:

Since $\dom_f=A$ and $\ran_f=B$, thus $\dom_g=B$ and $\ran_g=A$. $(y_1,x)\in f^{-1}$ and $(y_2,x)\in f^{-1}$ implies that $(x,y_1)\in f$ and $(x,y_2)\in f$, so $y_1=y_2$.

Comment: You should only enclose mathematical formulae with MathJax/Latex tags, not the text.

Comment: That is one of various equivalent definitions of an inverse function, e.g. that used by  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function). So we need to know which definition you are using in order to answer the question. The question is likely a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x\in A$ Write $f(x)=y$, $f(x)=y$ implies that $g(y)=g(f(x))=x$, we deduce that $g\circ f=id_A$

Let $y\in B$, write $g(y)=x$, $g(y)=x$ implies that $f(x)=f(g(y))=y$, we deduce that $f\circ g =id_B$.

Comment: It's all that I need for to prove? Is this a Theorem?